# Replace all non-alphanumeric characters in a string with an underscore

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I want to replace special characters (regex \W) with _ (underscore)
But I don't want to replace whitespace with underscore 
Also replace multiple consecutive special characters with single underscore

Example 
String: `The/Sun is red@`
Output: `The_Sun is red_`

String: `.//hack Moon`
Output: `_hack Moon`

I have tried `echo 'string' | sed 's/\W/_/g'` 
But it's not accurate

Comment: It should be noted the `\W` will match any character other than a word character. A word character is any alphabetic character, digit or `_` see [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#regexp-extensions) for details.

Comment: @potong thank you for the info, I just wanted to avoid any illegal characters in filenames

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**`sed`** approach:

```
s="The/Sun is red@ .//hack Moon"

sed -E 's/[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+/_/g' <<<"$s"
The_Sun is red_ _hack Moon
```

---

- `[^[:alnum:][:space:]]+` - match any character sequence except alphanumeric and whitespace

Answer (score 14):

Use [`tr`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tr.1.html) for that:

```bash
echo -n "The/Sun is red@" | tr -c -s '[:alnum:][:blank:]' '_'
```

- `[:alnum:][:blank:]` represents alphanumeric characters and whitespace
- `-c` (or `--complement`) means "use the opposite of that"
- Use `-s` (or `--squeeze-repeats`) to squeeze duplicate underscores into one

Comment: Please note that OP was also asking to *replace multiple consecutive special characters with a **single** underscore*.

Comment: @simlev Thanks for the comment. I overlooked that. `tr -s` will replace multiple repeated search characters with a single instance of the replacement character

Answer (score 4):

Just with bash parameter expansion, similar pattern to other answers:

```
shopt -s extglob
for str in "The/Sun is red@" ".//hack Moon"; do 
    echo "${str//+([^[:alnum:][:blank:]])/_}"
    # .........^^........................^  replace all
    # ...........^^.....................^    one or more
    # .............^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      non-alnum, non-space character
done
```

```
The_Sun is red_
_hack Moon
```